# Menu that fits any screen (auto resize width)

Tags: html, resize, width, screen

I'm making a menu that fits perfectly in any screen, but its height doesn't change (only its width).

The problem is: my menu is divided in 3 images (left, middle and right).
Middle image resizes to fit the screen (i putted 70%) but when the screen has smaller width, the sides of menu break lines, like that:

[image: On my screen]

[image: On smaller screens]

I need solutions for this, or other ways to make this menu!

It have to occupy the whole width and have the gradient on its sides.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script>
var onre = function(){
    var w = document.getElementById('make2fit').offsetWidth;
    var h = document.getElementById('make2fit').offsetHeight;
    var ww = window.innerWidth;
    var wh = window.innerHeight;
    var p = (Math.floor((ww/wh)*100)/100<1)?(ww/w):(wh/h);
    var nw = Math.round(w * p);
    var nh =  Math.round(h * p);
    document.getElementById("make2fit").width = nw;
    document.getElementById("make2fit").height = nh;    
}

window.onresize = onre;
window.onload = onre;
</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Silvania Miranda</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #030708;
}
div.menu {
    /* current css */
    min-width:960px; /* which is the current minimum width for designing website for desktops */
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    position:relative;
    top:510px;
    overflow:hidden;
    
}
ul li {
    /* current css */
    display:block; /* default display for list elements, could be omitted */
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    max-width:125px;
    min-width:50px;
    color:white;
}
ul {
    /* current css */
    overflow:hidden
}
div.mulher{
width:auto;
height:auto;
z-index:-1;
bottom:0px;
right:0px;
position:absolute;
}

div.fundo{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    bottom:15%;
    }

div.fundomenu{
    background:url(menufundo.png);
    width:80%;
    height:60px;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    z-index:0;
    float:left}
    
div.cantomenu
{position:relative;
height:60px;
width:156px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:100;
float:left}
div.esq{background:url(menupontae.png)}
div.dir{background:url(menupontad.png)}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="mulher"><img src="mulher.png" id="make2fit" style="margin:0px;"/></div>
<div class="fundo">

<div class="esq cantomenu"></div>
<div class="fundomenu"></div>
<div class="dir cantomenu"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the html and css for that? use jsfiddle if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Really safe option here would be to use table with 1 row and 3 columns. That would give you columns you want (left, right, middle) and the width will be maintained. With regards to background images for columns you might want to think how to design and cut them to make it look good.

another option here would be a combination of html css & javascript - the only problem is that if browser does not support JS, your website wouldn't look right.

Does that help?

Comment: Could you teach me step by step? Since i don't have many skills in html i don't know exactly how i'm supposed to do that in table.